# Special 'urls' with an @ sign like like git@github.com:user/myproject.git

Tags: git, url

When I look at some git commands, sometimes the url option is filled with some strange url with an @ sign. For example, `git clone git clone -b my-branch git@github.com:user/myproject.git`.

What's the format for this, and can any url like `http://example.com` be represented like that?

Or am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in several Git manual pages including [the one for `git clone`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS):

> An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:
>
> - [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/

which means that this is shorthand for `ssh://[user@]host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`.

(This particular extension is a special Git trick.  Most other URL-handlers do not treat arguments this way.)

Answer (score 1):

[The `userinfo@` prefix on the hostname has been part of URL syntax from the start](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), it's just less often encountered.